# How to resize attachement

Tags: uploads, images

I m having trouble in resizing media images. I tried [add_image_size](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size) function to resize my original image like below.

> add_image_size( 'my_thumb', 145, 100);

it creates thumb images with height 100 but it changes width for every image.
like some image `66x100,140X100` .How to make sure the width 145

Sorry could n't share links and screenshot due to low reputation

I tried also timthumb. getting same result.Where i'm stucking .

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `add_image_size` creates an image of specified size when you upload a new image into a gallery. Is that what you exactly want? Or you want to display an image with specified size? Then you need to use `the_post_thumbnail( 'your-size' );` in the loop.

Comment: @Alexey: yes i wanna display an image with specified size.But i couldn't use the_post_thumbnail because its an attachement

Comment: ok. [This code](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29618/conditional-statement-check-if-post-has-an-attachment-image/29619#29619) checks if post has attached images and display them. There is also possibility to specify your size.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to retroactively resize images, use the code you've supplied in your functions.php, then run the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

Once you've done that you should be able to display the image using the following:

```
the_post_thumbnail('my_thumb');
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add:

```
add_image_size( 'my_thumb', 145, 100, true);
```

Adding true should enable WordPress to do a hard crop to keep your dimensions and not just scale the image. (Provided your images are at least that width and height or larger.)

As mentioned above you would need to regenerate your current images.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you added your `add_image_size()` call to `functions.php` *after* you already uploaded/attached images, you will need to regenerate the thumbnails for those attached images.

Second, you should be able to return/output the image for any defined image size, using `wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, $size )`:

- [`wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) calls `wp_get_attachment_image_src()`
- [`wp_get_attachment_image_src()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) calls `image_downsize()`
- [`image_downsize()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/image_downsize) calls `wp_get_attachment_metadata()`
- [`wp_get_attachment_metadata()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata) returns the `_wp_attachment_metadata` post meta for the attachment
- `_wp_attachment_metadata` includes all pre-defined image sizes